# Change of folder Icon takes longer time to show the updated icon

Tags: c#, windows

I am on Windows 8 and I have C# code that changes a folder icon.

This works just fine however it takes a long time to refresh. I've been trying methods such as:

```
IntPtr path = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto(@"[FolderPath]");

SHChangeNotify(HChangeNotifyEventID.SHCNE_ATTRIBUTES, 
    HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_PATHA, path, IntPtr.Zero);

SHChangeNotify(HChangeNotifyEventID.SHCNE_UPDATEIMAGE, 
    HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_DWORD, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

SHChangeNotify(HChangeNotifyEventID.SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED,
    HChangeNotifyFlags.SHCNF_IDLIST, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

This doesn't seem to have any affect on the folder icon. It does refresh my screen but the icon is still the same icon. Several minutes later I can press F5 and it will change to the folder icon I specified.

I've seen some really ugly ways to get around this but I would really like to know what will tell windows to 'refresh' the folder icon programmatically. I've seen that dropbox seems to be instant and I'm thinking that there is a solution.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? I have the same problem, working with java. Any input would help!

Comment: Google "refresh shell icon cache" to get ahead.

Answer (score 0):

you may use the nuget package[windows Icon Changer]
also you can take a look at the source code, that defines how you can do.
tldr: you you to have pInvoke methods to modify desktop.ini instead of directly editing.
If you manually edit the desktop.ini, even SChangeNotify would not work instantly

[Disclaimer- I'm the author https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nakshatra.Windows.IconChanger/

Answer (score 0):

see my solution here. You need to add a "non zero width" space to the folder name to trigger an instant refresh of the folder icon.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78221091/23796906

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

To change the Folder icon it needs two steps to achieve this:

```
Step 1. Create a desktop.ini file inside the folder for which to create the icon (the "Target Folder").
Step 2. Set the Target Folder's attribute to "System".
```

To accomplish these steps, create two classes i.e. FolderIcon, which orchestrates the steps and IniWriter, which just has one static method called WriteValue() that wraps the WritePrivateProfileString() Win32 API function.

To getting all these things done in a right way, just follow this code project tutorial:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9331/Create-Icons-for-Folders-in-Windows-Explorer-Using

Comment: Please summarize the solution from the link in your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer however as my question states I already know how to do that and it is working fine. The question is that it takes several minutes for that icon to actually change. I can press F5 to refresh etc but it still won't change. Then all of a sudden the icon will change to the icon I specified. I need to know what windows function I need to call to force the image update.

Comment: @hobeau: I have not investigated a lot on the code provided by you. The code what I have shared is well tested & changes the folder icon instantly. You can go with this approach & verify the same by downloading the sample app from the CodeProject.

Comment: Yeah this is the codebase I've used in my project. I've used the demo application and in my Windows8 machine the icon doesn't change instantly. It changes eventually but it takes several minutes.