# Change Directory (folder) icon using C# programmatically

Tags: c#, windows

I want to change icon of particular folder's icons on Windows platform using C#

Comment: @Prajwal: Unfortunately, the duplicate questions are answered very poorly.

Comment: Existing Question is good but their problem to forget the remove *`desktop.ini`* file in particular *folder* before change the icon it really working perfectly.

Comment: I just posted a complete solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531898/c-sharp-how-to-set-folder-icon/60918342#60918342

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can update the folder icon by specifying it in the `desktop.ini` file

```
private static void ApplyFolderIcon(string targetFolderPath, string iconFilePath)
{
    var iniPath = Path.Combine(targetFolderPath, "desktop.ini");
    if (File.Exists(iniPath))
    {
        //remove hidden and system attributes to make ini file writable
        File.SetAttributes(
           iniPath, 
           File.GetAttributes(iniPath) & 
           ~( FileAttributes.Hidden | FileAttributes.System) );
    }

    //create new ini file with the required contents
    var iniContents = new StringBuilder()
        .AppendLine("[.ShellClassInfo]")
        .AppendLine($"IconResource={iconFilePath},0")
        .AppendLine($"IconFile={iconFilePath}")
        .AppendLine("IconIndex=0")
        .ToString();
    File.WriteAllText(iniPath, iniContents);

    //hide the ini file and set it as system
    File.SetAttributes(
       iniPath, 
       File.GetAttributes(iniPath) | FileAttributes.Hidden | FileAttributes.System );
    //set the folder as system
    File.SetAttributes(
        targetFolderPath, 
        File.GetAttributes(targetFolderPath) | FileAttributes.System );
}
```

If you now right-click the folder, you will see that the icon is updated. It might take a while before the change is applied in the file explorer as well.

I have been trying to find a way to apply the changes immediately, but so far without luck. There is a `SHChangeNotify` shell function that should do just that, but it doesn't seem to work with folders.

**Note** we have to remove the `System` and `Hidden` attributes from the `ini` file in the beginning, otherwise `File.WriteAllText` will fail because you don't have permissions to modify it.

Comment: I searched and found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/how-to-customize-folders-with-desktop-ini which links here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathmakesystemfoldera and tested it: After giving my still default looking folder the desktop.ini file, I used "attrib +S" ON THE FOLDER. And instantly, I saw the folder with icon in an already open explorer window. Removed the flag again - folder looked default. Is this viable!?!? E.g. "dir" command does NOT show that folder any longer (by default). :P

Comment: Setting system attribute to the folder really does the work and is documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-customize-folders-with-desktop-ini, however it's not exactly the same with the user action "Folder Properties - Customize - Change Icon". The "Hidden" checkbox is greyed out on system folder properties, while a user-clicked-icon-applied folder is not "system". Thanks that's the only anwser to programmatically setting folder icon I found til now.

Comment: Do not edit desktop.ini manually, instead use pInvoke methods and your icon will set and refresh instantly,

you may use the nuget package[windows Icon Changer] also you can take a look at the source code, that defines how you can do. tldr: you you to have pInvoke methods to modify desktop.ini instead of directly editing. If you manually edit the desktop.ini, even SChangeNotify would not work instantly

[Disclaimer- I'm the author https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nakshatra.Windows.IconChanger/